# Object not deserializing properly

Tags: java, tomcat, serialization

I have an object that contains a ConcurrentHashMap. I initialize the map with two keys. After serializing it to file I examine it and see it has the two keys. Then I deserialize it and sometimes I find it has only one key. Since it happens only occasionally I'd guess it's some sort of parallelism issue but I still don't understand how partial initialization is possible? Is there a good way to debug this?

If it's of any help this happens within the context of Tomcat de/serializing into a file using FileStore and PersistentManager.

Comment: why not serialize only the map content (so items inside) ?

Comment: I need the whole object.